# git-p4: sync p4 changes to git repo

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I'm moving our project from perforce to git. After a few setups and by the [guide](http://www.partario.com/blog/2009/06/moving-a-perforce-project-to-github.html), I successfully created my git repo and imported source from perforce. Then I ran into problem that I can't simply import subsequent p4 changes to git repo. (Most of us are still working on perforce).

1. git-p4 sync
2. git push origin master

got following error

> [rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward) error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:xxx/yyyyy.git' hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') hint: before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

I also tried

1. git-p4 sync
2. git-p4 rebase
3. git pull
4. git push

which worked finally. But I've no idea why.

The git-p4 sync manual said

> After an initial import you can easily synchronize your git repository with
>   newer changes from the Perforce depot by just calling
>     git-p4 sync
>   in your git repository. By default the "remotes/p4/master" branch is updated.

So I guessed that's why subsequent 'git push' didn't work. Do I have to rebase/pull/push every time?
Do I miss something? I'm new to git, please help.

Comment: what is your goal with 'git push origin master'

Comment: @Casey, push source to remote repo on github

Comment: There is alternative tool you may be interested in: [git-p4s](http://lm1.github.io/git-p4s/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are pushing code to a standard git repo, and it's rejected then you need to rebase your changes onto `origin/master`.

Comment: After days of testing, I finally figured out 'rebase' did the trick, git-p4 sync, git-p4 rebase, git push, that's all.